# simple html dom ul class

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the content of `ul` tag with multiple class names. The same syntax works for div tags but cant get it to work with the `ul` tag below. It just returns empty array.

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul class="set-left farm margin-exclude">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Below just returns empty Array.

```
$html->find('ul[class=set-left farm margin-exclude]');
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264525/php-simple-html-dom-parser-select-only-divs-with-multiple-classes

It seems that you've to find one class and check the result list with the second and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working code at my end:-

file.txt:-

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul class="set-left farm margin-exclude">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="set-left farm margin-exclude">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

query.php:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include_once('simple_html_dom.php'); // this is parser file
$html = file_get_html('file.txt');


$level_items = $html->find('*[class="set-left farm margin-exclude"]');

foreach ( $level_items as $item ) {
   echo $item;
}
```

Output on browser:- http://i.share.pho.to/92745ee0_o.png

Note:- download parser file here:- https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

You can use different way like:-

```
$html->find('ul.set-left');
```

OR

```
$html->find('.set-left.farm.margin-exclude');
```

OR

```
$html->find('*[set-left.farm.margin-exclude]');
```

Comment: This returns all elements containing that class name. I would like to be more specific and target only those classes in the same tag.

Comment: Sorry, I want to find the ul tag that contains all those tree classes (set-left farm margin-exclude). Not just set-left.

Comment: Returns empty array, douple/triple checked the names of the tags. Have been struggling with this for several hours now. :(

Comment: @user3604481  i have added three solution. Check all.

Comment: Can see that it should work so will mark your answer as correct, have to do it some other way. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
$html->find('ul.set-left.farm.margin-exclude');
```

Comment: Still empty array :(

Comment: are you sure that you wrote the classes correctly in your html, since this would be the correct way to find something with multiple classes.

Comment: Strange, getting empty array as soon as i add second class :( Working with only one class specified.